# Why am i getting doubled frequency for chirp spectrogram

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, spectrogram

I wrote this code to generate linear fmcw chirps:

```
def generate_fmcw(BW, Tc, Fs, initial_phase=0, num_chirps=2, delay=0):
        t = np.arange(0, Tc-1/Fs, 1 / Fs)
        nsamples = len(t)
        w = 2 * pi * np.linspace(0, BW, nsamples)
        return np.tile(np.cos(w * (t-delay) + initial_phase), num_chirps)
```

When using:

```
BW = 1e6
Tc = 2e-3
Fs = 2e6
num_chirps = 1
```

and this spectrogram function using *scipy* and *pyplot*:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import signal

def display_spectrogram(s,fs):
    f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(s, fs,mode='magnitude')
    plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
    plt.show()
```

I get some undersampling behaviour:

```
a = generate_fmcw(BW, Tc,Fs,num_chirps=1)
display_spectrogram(a,Fs)
```

[undersampled fmcw chirp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEK2M.png)

But when I use :

```
Fs = 4e6
```

I get double max frequency I wanted (which was BW):
[double frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAzxr.png)

Why am I getting this weird behaviour? I am using the right sampling frequency according to nyquist theorem...

Comment: Are you aware of [`scipy.signal.chirp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html)?

Comment: To create a linear chirp, the argument to `cos` must be the integral of the time-varying frequency.  Another way to say it is: For a function θ(t), the instantaneous frequency of cos(θ(t)) is θ'(t) (the derivative of θ(t)).  Your expression is roughly `c*t*(t-d) + i`, and the derivatve of that is `2*c*t - c*d`, hence the doubling of the frequency.  Just include an additional factor of 0.5 in your expression.

Comment: See my second comment.

Comment: Thanks Sir! you helped me a lot! please make this an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a time-varying frequency such as a linear chirp, the argument to `cos` must be the integral of the time-varying frequency. Another way to say it is: for a function θ(t), the instantaneous frequency of cos(θ(t)) is θ'(t) (the derivative of θ(t)). Your expression is basically equivalent to `c*(t-d)**2 + i`, and the derivative of that is `2*c*t - c*d`, hence the doubling of the frequency.  The solution is to adjust the argument of `cos` so that the derivative of the expression is the desired time-varying frequency.

Also, you be might interested in [`scipy.signal.chirp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.chirp.html).